# Flutter Post API in Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios, flutter-android

The Post API is working in Android but it is giving 403 Forbidden Error in ISO phone when I run it. I am also getting the output in Thunder VSC, Postman, and my Android Flutter Application. But I am not getting Output or response in IOS iPhone.Please can anyone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide log of error or at least screenshot?

Comment: Yes sir Provided. It is working in Android but not working in IOS

Comment: API returns 403, can you provide also a log from that API? Then it looks like you are still trying to parse something, wich fails obviously in Json serialization, but there must be also an error before, inside API call.

Comment: yeah sent you sir

Comment: yea that's your API method, but I need to see the result of that HTTP Post which crashed with 403, can you wrap inside of that method in try/catch and print out error after Post is called? or can you provide the result loginResponseToken immediately after that http.post?

Comment: We need to find why did your request returned 403

Comment: How to solve it]

Comment: Issue Solved bRo Thank you so much 
The issue is VPN it will only work in my province 
Its a condition from Backend
Thank you so much for your Time and Support sir